# How to parse XHTML with unexpected errors

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading a XML (with XmlDocument) with some html inside of it. But sometimes i got a bad formatted XML something lie this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<mocktag/>?<mock_tag=<moc
    ktag/>&mocktag_2=<mockta
    g/>
    </head> 
    </html>
```

As you can see i have bad formatted tags and for that reason it causes my program to crash. So my question is any way to read the xml string correctly? Maybe transform this string into a one-line string?

Comment: You could run a regex that looks for a newline + spaces and remove them. Hopefully that wouldn't adversely affect other legitimate content.

Comment: *"sometimes i got a bad formatted XML"* - you should rather improve the method of obtaining xml than attempting to fix bad result.

Comment: This XML doesn't have tags broken by newlines. It has hopeless garble from `content="0;` to just before `</head>`. OP, how many different forms does the `mocktag` garble take? Is it regular enough to reliably search for?

Comment: Agree with @EdPlunkett. If you "fix" those tags, you still have invalid xml. You have meta tag like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). In your xml there is `">` missing before `</head>`. You should contact one who generates this xml.

Comment: The html is bad, not the xml.  The html wasn't encoded properly.  The are invalid html characters like the ampersand. See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: @jdweng To be fair, it's meant to be xhtml, which IIRC ought to be valid XML. And there's a missing close quote too, if the garble is intended to be the content attribute for the meta tag.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too.  This hybrid code is neither xhtml, html, or xml.  No matter how you look at it is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format it into one line you can use Regex:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Should remove every spaces and put every line into one.

Comment: Have you tested this solution on the example XML that OP provided in the question?

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I tested your solution and i guess everything works fine. I'll need just to double check again if i break something else. but so far working :)